# How to establish (TCP) LAN socket connection with C# client and Python server?

Tags: python, c#, sockets, tcp, connection

I managed to do it in python client-server but not with c# client.

I guess the problem is with the IP version or protocol type, maybe some socket option.

Python:

```
import socket

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
socket.bind(("127.0.0.1", 3012))
socket.listen(0)

while True:
    print(f"server is listening on {socket.getsockname()}")
    sclient, address = socket.accept()
    print(f"Connection made from {address}.")
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry("127.0.0.1");
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[4];
            IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, 3012);

            Socket client = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            client.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
        }
    }
}
```

`exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: refused connection`

Comment: What is your socket error code? That should be a good starting point to try and nail down the issue.

Comment: Try adding a `try{}` `catch{}` to retrieve your socket error code`try {ConnectionMethodHere}catch (System.Net.Sockets.SocketException sockEx) {int errorCode = sockEx.ErrorCode;}`

Comment: The Net library does not allow you from client connect to the loopback address 127.0.0.1.  Use instead the IP address or the machine or the computer name.

Comment: Why do you use DNS to connect to localhost? Just use IPAddress.Parse(). Probably what's happening is that you're connecting to the IP assigned to your NIC, and the firewall is blocking that.